# Is there a way to refer pom when added as a dependency in a dependent project?

Tags: maven

As per requirements the resources files(custom pmd rulesets) are included in main project where plugin is added in  pom.xml and also defined custom goals in pom.xml. so when added main project as a dependency in other projects can it perform pmd checks in my dependent project as the same way it did in my main project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Maven uses the POM of dependencies only to determine further (transitive) dependencies. It does not read or execute plugins defined in dependencies.

If you want to make common configuration of plugins for several projects, use Parent POMs.

Comment: Ok . so Is there any other way to do it ? other than parent approach . Since i already achieved it but i want to achieve it as a dependency

Comment: It cannot be done through the dependency mechanism, and it is not how Maven works. If you want to centralize plugin configuration, you use a parent pom. Or you need to call the goals standalone from the command line.